# Moving an object from point A to point B in a straight line at a constant speed

Tags: java, android

So essentially what I've been trying to do is to get an object (the player) to fire a bullet in a straight line from it in angle and then just continue on, so if the 'gun' is pointed at an angle of 35 degrees (with 0 degrees being to the right of the screen adding up to 360 going counter-clockwise) then the bullet will travel at a constant speed (say 5) at that angle from the origin.

Because the way I've been doing my movement is I've had a function called update that would handle all the drawing and what not. Then when it came to movement it would just add a vertical speed and a horizontal speed to the already existing x and y, and it's just been too hard to try to work around it so that it adds a suitable horizontal and vertical speed to move at that angle at a constant speed, so any help will be appreciated.
-Heath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can make your update() method to measure time since it was last invoked, and update location of bullet based on that?
It would make bullet to move at approximately constant speed. (given that FPS is big enough)

EDIT2:

> ```
> public class Bullet {
>   // speed is in units/second
>   // angle is in radians
>   double x;
>   double y;
>   double sv;
>   double sh;
>   public Bullet(double x, double y, double angle, double speed) {
>     this.x = x;
>     this.y = y;
>     sv = Math.sin(angle)*speed;
>     sh = Math.cos(angle)*speed;
>     last_updated = System.currentTimeMillis();
>   }
>
>   long last_updated;
>
>   public void update() {
>     long time_elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - last_updated;
>     last_updated = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
>     this.x += this.hs*(this.time_elapsed/1000)
>     this.y += this.vs*(this.time_elapsed/1000)
>   }
> }
> ```

Maybe you'll need to play with angle to make it suitable for your coordinate system. (something like negate the angle, add/substract Pi, and so on.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I could try that but i still dont have it moving properly

Comment: Could you post code for that method? Somewhere like pastebin.com. We then will be able to look at it and suggest something.

Comment: its pretty much

creation:bullet(x,y,vs,hs)/update:update(){this.x+=vs; this.y+=hs;}

Comment: its nothing special just the basic calls to draw squares and what not

Comment: although your edit is nice and all it still doesn't address the issue I'm having with getting the bullet to travel in a straight line from its point of origin

what i'm trying to de able to do is just have a function that goes createBullet(x,y,angle,speed) x and y being the point where it is created, angle being the direction it moves and speed being the speed it travels at, any ideas?

Comment: Ah. I'll post another snippet now.

Comment: Edited that code. I hope I finally understood what you wanted to see.